# How to replace numbers in a file by awk and gsub (replace -1, 0, 1 and 2 by NA, 0101, 0102 and 0202 respectively)?

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I have a file like this:

```
hgfjk
AX-75183725 2 2 -1 2 1 2 -1 0
```

and I want to replace `-1`, `0`, `1` and `2` by `NA`, `0101`, `0102` and `0202` respectively. so I would get:

```
hgfjk
AX-75183725 0202 0202 NA 0202 0101 0202 NA 0101
```

and I use this command:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print; next } NR>1{a=$1;$1="@";gsub(/ -1\>/,"NA");gsub(/<0\>/,"0101");gsub(/<1\>/,"0102");gsub(/\<2\>/,"0202");$1=a;print}' file > out
```

which gives me this output:

```
hgfjk
AX-75183725 0202 2NA 0202 0102 2NA 0101
```

I don't know what is wrong!! can someone help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array with the values to substitute. And will calculate each position for every field but the first one.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        subs="NA 0101 0102 0202";
        split( subs, subs_arr );
    }
    NR == 1 { 
        print; 
        next 
    } 
    NR>1{
        for ( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) {
            $i = subs_arr[ $i + 2 ];
        }
        print
    }
' file
```

Run previous command and will get following output:

```
hgfjk
AX-75183725 0202 0202 NA 0202 0102 0202 NA 0101
```

---

**EDIT**: I gave a solution but I guess yours doesn't work because of `gsub(/<0\>/,"0101")` and `gsub(/<1\>/,"0102")`. You should escape `<` too, like: `gsub(/\<0\>/,"0101")` and `gsub(/\<1\>/,"0102")`